# order and organize array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects and I want to organize the objects based on their units like this:

```
const array = [
  { unit: 5, id: 'five'},
  { unit: 200, id: 'some22'},
  { unit: 100, id: 'recall'},
  { unit: 5, id: 'some'},
];

// Result :

[

  [ { unit: 5, id: 'five'}, { unit: 5, id: 'some'}, ],
  [ { unit: 6, id: 'some22'} ],
  [ { unit: 55, id: 'recall'} ],

]
```

Note: we can simply  use filter method to get the array but in my case we don't know the units and we just want to order and organize them

Comment: can you show some research you have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)**:

```js
const array = [
    { unit: 5, id: 'five'},
    { unit: 200, id: 'some22'},
    { unit: 100, id: 'recall'},
    { unit: 5, id: 'some'},
];

const unitGroups = new Map();
for (const obj of array) {
    if (!unitGroups.has(obj.unit)) {
        unitGroups.set(obj.unit, []);
    }
    unitGroups.get(obj.unit).push(obj);
}

const result = Array.from(unitGroups.values());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using the build in array method `reduce`, just to create a *one-liner*. Details to the under appreciated `reduce` function [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
// Initial Data
const array = [
  { unit: 5, id: 'five'},
  { unit: 200, id: 'some22'},
  { unit: 100, id: 'recall'},
  { unit: 5, id: 'some'},
];

let result = array.reduce (function(last, next){ 
  // find index of a List with matching unit
  let index = last.findIndex((itemList) => itemList.some( item => item.unit == next.unit)); 
  if(index == -1){ // if no match was found
    index = last.push([]) - 1; // add an empty Array and set the index
  }
  last[index].push(next);  // add the Entry to the selected List
  return last;
}, [])

console.info(result);
```

**btw.:** I'm asuming the posted *result data* is incorrect, since the "units" for **some22** and **recall** don't match with the initial data. If this assumption is wrong please clarify

**Extra:** just for kicks and giggles the whole thing as a real one-liner:
*( Don't try this at home ;-) )*

```js
const array = [
  { unit: 5, id: 'five'},
  { unit: 200, id: 'some22'},
  { unit: 100, id: 'recall'},
  { unit: 5, id: 'some'},
];

console.info( array.reduce((p, c) => ((p.find( l => l.some(i => i.unit == c.unit)) || p[p.push([]) - 1]).push(c), p), []));
```